# How would you add custom domain name to a k8s cluster within Jelastic Cloud

Tags: kubernetes, jelastic, virtuozzo

I'm currently deploying a Keycloak instance in production using Kubernetes, and I'm hosting my project on the Infomaniak jelastic platform. I'm new to Kubernetes and I'm facing challenges in adding public IPv4 and IPv6 addresses to my Kubernetes cluster. I understand that I need to use Ingress to expose my cluster to the internet, but I'm encountering issues with the external IP, which remains in a pending status. Additionally, I'm unsure how to configure both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. According to the Jelastic documentation, [here](https://www.virtuozzo.com/company/blog/kubernetes-public-ip-address/) following the first method provided does not seem to work for me. If anyone has experience or expertise in this area, I would greatly appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this [documentation](https://www.virtuozzo.com/company/blog/custom-domain-names-for-jelastic-deployments/) for adding custom domain names for Jelastic deployments. you can consider these steps:

1. Login to your own domain registrator and add the canonical name (CNAME)
2. Wait til the DNS change propagates. (Usually takes 72 hours)
3. Login to Jelastic
4. Click the **Settings** button for the environment which URL you wish to change
5. Enter your domain name
6. Click the **Bind** button.

Given that the Jelastic Kubernetes clusters might not natively support assigning public IPV4 and IPV6 addresses directly to deployments.

You can try these approaches:

1. LoadBalancer Service with External Provider:

   - Use a Load Balancer service in your kubernetes cluster that points to your Keycloak pods
   - Configure the Load Balancer to use external IPV4 and IPV6 addresses provided by Jelastic(if available)
2. Ingress Controller with External Provider:

   - Deploy an Ingress controller like nginx Ingress controller in your cluster
   - Configure teh ingress controller to use external IPV4 and IPV6 addresses provided by Jelastic.
   - This approach offers more flexibility and control over routing rules.
3. Cloud Load Balancing Service:

   - If Jelastic offers a cloud load balancing service, consider integrating with Kubernetes cluster.
   - This service might manage both IPV4 and IPV6 traffic and simplify configuration.